# How to find first value of math expression in C (for loop)

Tags: c, for-loop

I have written a program which shows me all values of this math expression: (ABC)=(AB)*(AB)-C*C.
A,B,C are the digits of the number. The question is: How can i write program that shows me only FIRST value of this expression? Thanks

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a,b,c;

    for(a=1;a<10;a++)
        for(b=0;b<10;b++)
            for(c=0;c<10;c++)
                if((a*100+b*10+c*1)==(a*10+b*1)*(a*10+b*1)-(c*c))
                    printf("%d%d%d\n",a,b,c);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: exit in the printf block?

Comment: why don't you use break in the if scope?

Comment: When you say "first value" do you want A, ABC, or the first A, B, and C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add count, then check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int a,b,c,count;
count = 0;
for(a=1;a<10;a++)
    for(b=0;b<10;b++)
        for(c=0;c<10;c++)
if((a*100+b*10+c*1)==(a*10+b*1)*(a*10+b*1)-(c*c))
count++;
if(count == 1)
{
   printf("%d%d%d\n",a,b,c);
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: this works, just i had to add brackets before "count++;" and before "system("pause");. Thanks man